# Generic of subclass in java

Tags: java, generics

I have the following snippet of code where I implement Bag container, and the Bag class implement Iterable interface.

```
public class ResizingArrayBag<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {
    //Some bag methods
    private class ListIterator<Item> implements Iterator<Item> {
    //ListIterator methods
    }
}
```

Are the `Item` in `ListIterator<Item>` class different from `Item` in `ResizeingArrayBag<Item>`?

Why do we have declare `Iterable` and `Iterator` with `Item` and are the `Item`s in these different from `ListIterator<Item>` and `ResizingArrayBag<Item>`?

Comment: `Item` is the same class in both cases. If your class implements `Iterable<Item>`, it means that it has a method that returns an `Iterator<Item>` that defines how the elements (`Item`s) inside will be iterated. (next, hasNext, remove)

Comment: Inner classes are syntactic sugar and there is no need to have the two types equal, but it is required nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the `Item` in `ListIterator<Item>` class different from `Item` in `ResizeingArrayBag<Item>`?

Yes. This is called *type-parameter hiding* and it's discouraged, because it can lead to serious confusion. For example, it would be possible to provide this statement:

```
 ResizingArrayBag<A>.ListIterator<B> x = new ResizingArrayBag<A>().ListIterator<B>();
```

where `A` and `B` are some different real types.

If the `ListIterator` is supposed to hold the same elements as the enclosing `ResizeingArrayBag` type, then you have to do:

```
public class ResizingArrayBag<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {
    //Some bag methods
    private class ListIterator implements Iterator<Item> {
    //ListIterator methods
    }
}
```

Note that here we're not redefining an `Item` type-parameter, but rather reusing the already defined one for `ResizingArrayBag`.

Another *rule of thumb* is that you should name your type-parameters with single, capital letters. `Item` could be misleading, especially if somewhere out there some specific type, called `Item`, exists.

So, instead of naming your type-parameter `Item` prefer something like:

```
public class ResizingArrayBag<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    private class ListIterator implements Iterator<T> {

    }
}
```

> Why do we have declare `Iterable` and `Iterator` with `Item` and are the `Item`s in these different from `ListIterator<Item>` and `ResizingArrayBag<Item>`?

Implementing `Iterable` will force you implement the `.iterator()` method, where you have to return an `Iterator` implementation.

Comment: Could you give me an example in which inner class and parent class have different Item in client test?

Comment: Yes. It's possible to write: `new OuterClass<A>().new InnerClass<B>()`, where `A` and `B` a different types. This is not safe. :)